# ros kinect roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

Tags: kinect, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to every body

I have installed ros on ubuntu 10.04 then I have installed kinect drivers following http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

1.-  I run roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

I get the following errors:

Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]

Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]

Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/acp/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00361808210049A.yaml]

Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/acp/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00361808210049A.yaml]

then the system hangs in

Exiting onInitImpl()

I have no clue about these errors, any suggestion or solution will be appreciated.

Regards, Alfredo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11925/ros-kinect--roslaunch-openni_launch-openni.launch/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2011-11-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-11-21**:
select the correct fixed frame (camera_link for example), then add a point cloud 2 plugin and select the topic /camera/depth_registered/points or /camera/depth/points if you haven't checked the register point cloud in dynamic reconfigure.

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2011-11-17**:
well, how do you preformatted text :)  yea I could open rviz, how do you visualize the point cloud with rviz?

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-11-14**:
Have you tried visualizing the point cloud in rviz? The launch file just starts the driver, etc.. not the visualizer.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-11-13**:
could you give more details about how you installed the drivers? When you run the node make sure its not running already. Pls post the commands and codes in "preformatted text". It makes things clear and easy to analyse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Alfredo,

I got the same error msg with the new openni_launch file. But to get rid of the error massage for the calibration you should follow these instructions http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera/calibration

after the calibration you will have the needed calibration files in the right folder.
But I have no idea how to fix the advertising problem.

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2011-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2011-11-17**:
cool, I will try that, thanx :)